# Problems creating a Castle.Windsor interceptor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, interceptor

Ok, I am officially losing my mind over this ...

I am trying to create a Castle.Windsor interceptor, but resolving from the container keeps throwing this exception:

```
DependencyResolverException: An interceptor registered for 
DI_Test.DatabaseService doesn't implement the IInterceptor interface
```

As far as I can see I have done everything by the book, and the container contents (in debug-mode) doesn't report any mal-configured services.

Configuration of the container:

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container
            .Register(Component.For<Runner>())
            .Register(Component.For<IDataDependency>()
                .ImplementedBy<DatabaseService>()
                .LifestyleSingleton()
                .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForKey("wait")).Anywhere)
            .Register(Component.For<WaitAndRetryInterceptor>().LifeStyle.Singleton
                .Named("wait"))
            ;
    }
}
```

My interceptor:

```
public class WaitAndRetryInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My program:

```
public class Runner
{
    public void Run()
    {
        _dataDependency.GetData();
    }

    public Runner(IDataDependency dataDependency)
    {
        _dataDependency = dataDependency;
    }
    private readonly IDataDependency _dataDependency;
}

public interface IDataDependency
{
    void GetData();
}

public class DatabaseService : IDataDependency
{
    public void GetData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The program works perfectly without the configuration of the interceptor.

What I cannot figure out is WHY it throws this exception. The interceptor is clearly implementing the IInterceptor interface ... so what is the problem?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works for me.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky WAT? That makes no sense ;-) . I have added my entire code to https://bitbucket.org/jlundstocholm/castle.windsor.interceptor , could I ask you to test the full source? I am running Visual Studio 2017 Ent (latest update) in a Hyper-V VM (both host and VM are Win 10). Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two interfaces named `IInterceptor`

- `Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor`
- `Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor`

Not sure what is the difference between them, but to get it working you must use the first one.